# Eclipse, appcompat and themes No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This might seem like a duplicate but it isn't.(None of the other questions have the same situation).

In eclipse, a newly created application, right after i create it shows errors everytime, the app won't work. It is getting so frustrating.
Facts:
I don't have `appcompat_v7` in my package explorer
I can't find `android support library` in the sdk library (obsolete is checked)

`Broken Source package` in sdk manager extras, that I can't delete

My log:

```
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:40 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:44 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit] 
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit] C:\Users\Adminstrator\workspace\Rabbit\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2017-02-19 18:52:51 - Rabbit]
```

Comment: Official support for Eclipse for Android app development ended some months ago.

Comment: For real? I have been using ellipse for almost 4 years now! So what now?

Comment: "For real?" -- um, yes. "So what now?" -- Android Studio debuted a few years ago and is [the official IDE for Android app development](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).